# Unable to run my application on Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment

I have my github source here https://github.com/pramadae/Monkey and deployed it on heroku. And https://immense-harbor-7247.herokuapp.com/ is my heroku app link. Unfortunately I could not run my application. Please help me.

Comment: also unable to run with ''foreman start web''.

Comment: run `heroku logs` and look for the error message. Normally there is a clue in the logs.

Comment: logs  http://pastebin.com/VWX5xrY3 after updating Procfile as per "florpor" comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Procfile to:

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a 500 from your deployment - seems like you just have some error in your code..?